# Conversion from 'myItem*' to non-scalar type 'myItem' requested

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct MyItem
{
  int value;
  MyItem* nextItem;
};

int main() {
    MyItem item = new MyItem;
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the error:

```
error: conversion from `MyItem*' to non-scalar type `MyItem' requested
```

Compiling with g++.  What does that mean?  And what's going on here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try:

```
MyItem * item = new MyItem;
```

But do not forget to delete it after usage:

```
delete item;
```

Comment: I tried *item. think the space in between matters? The linux servers just crashed to I'll have to wait for them to come back up before I can try it with the space between then * and item.

Comment: @kralco: No, it doesn't matter. Do you have an introductory C++ book?

Comment: No. I'm taking a operating systems class. Ive taken a ton of programming classes in Java and used C# and still at work extensively. however neither of those languages use pointers like C/C++. This is just part of a larger project with implementing a program that does pipelining, (even though linux has it built in). 
i have the whole thing written and I get just this error.

Comment: Sorry, If i didn't make myself clear, I tried MyItem *item = new MyItem and still got and error.

Comment: @kralco: Post your real code in the question, then. You should get [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you want to program in C++, it's not going to happen by guessing.

Comment: @kralco If you got an error when trying `MyItem *item` then it should have been different than the first error. What did it say?

Answer (score 30):

You've mixed

```
MyItem item;
```

which allocates an instance of `MyItem` on the stack.  The memory for the instance is automatically freed at the end of the enclosing scope

and

```
MyItem * item = new MyItem;
```

which allocates an instance of `MyItem` on the heap.  You would refer to this instance using a pointer and would be required to explicitly free the memory when finished using `delete item`.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, this code won't compile because you forgot the semi-colons after each member variable declaration and after `MyItem` declaration and the keyword "struct" is typed wrong. Your code should look like this:

```
struct MyItem
{
var value;
MyItem* nextItem;
};

MyItem item = new MyItem;
```

Now answering your question, this code does not work because the new operator returns a pointer to the object created (a value of type `MyItem*`) and you are trying to assign this pointer to a variable of type `MyItem`. The compiler does not allow you to do this (because the value and the variable have different types). You should store the pointer into an apropriate variable, like this:

```
MyItem* item = new MyItem;
```

In this case, you must remember to `delete item` to avoid memory leak once you no more need it.

Alternatively, you can create the object in the stack without the `new` operator.

```
MyItem item;
```

In this case, the object ceases to exist when the function returns; you don't need to remember to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is edited code with changes mentioned on the right

```
struct MyItem                  // corrected spelling struct
{
    var value;                 // added ;
    struct MyItem * nextItem;  // add "struct" and added ;
};                             // added ;

MyItem * item = new MyItem;    // added * before item

delete item;                   // not exactly here, but some where in your code
```

BTW, you don't *have to* do `new`. You can possible create a `MyItem` object on the stack as

```
MyItem anotherItem;
```

Comment: ya, but the requirement is that we use new :(. As soon as the linux servers that crash about 30 minutes ago come back up i'll try it out.